# What is the best approach to protect against BYOD?

Tags: network

I would like to know briefly what are the best practice to protect corporate network from BYOD challenges nowadays?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A relatively efficient way to cope with "BYOD challenges" is to do the two following things:

1. Ban BYOD. Employees are explicitly forbidden to use "their own devices" for work-related operations. If they have a smartphone, they may use it to listen to music, but they must not plug it into their desktop computer or store work document on it.
2. Make a survey with users to understand *why* users want to "bring their own device". When a user wants to use his tablet or laptop on his workplace, this is not just for the sake of it, but because that device offers some functionality that his official, approved desktop computer does not fulfil. Simply banning BYOD will not be effective unless you carefully analyse what the users are looking for, and is lacking from the tools you provide.

Both steps are equally important; the second step is the most often forgotten by overzealous security officers.

Otherwise, if you are really intent on allowing employees to use their own devices for their work, then "best practice" is to enforce some sort of "security suite" on the device itself, at which point the device is no longer really the *user's* device; it is more like a company device that was paid by the employee. This tends to lead to some disgruntlement, which cancels the alleged benefits of BYOD (BYOD is supposed to increase productivity through the feeling of comfort and empowerment that employees derive from their using their own tools; that feeling is all too easy to destroy inadvertently with an inappropriate requirement for installation of extra police software which users will resent as an intrusion).